# Python Flask url_for (static) with variable

Tags: python, flask

i'm using [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) with Python and want to insert an Image.

 
That works fine with following command:

```
{{ url_for('static', filename='path/to/img.jpg') }}
```

But now i want to insert an image in a loop (like for articles) and need the path out of a variable like:

```
{{ article.header_img_path }}
```

How can i insert a variable path into the

> {{ url_for('static', filename='path/to/img.jpg') }}

command?

Something like that:

```
{{ url_for('static', filename=' {{ article.header_img_path }} ') }}
```

Is there a better way to do that or is just my syntax corrupt?

Thanks for your advise!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable should be passed to `filename` without quotes or braces.

```
{{ url_for('static', filename=article.header_img_path) }}
```