# Display image with variable and URL_FOR - Flask

Tags: python, flask

My target is to display an image on a website, with Flask.

The image is in :

```
/static/img/articles
```

The image name is : "43.jpg"

Hardcoding it is perfectly working :

```
<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/articles/43.jpg') }}" alt="no picture">
```

However, i need the path to be dynamic (the image is 43 today, maybe 17 tomrrow and 58 after tomorrow).

I tried everything, for example this :

last_id_jpg = r"img/article/43.jpg"

```
return render_template("index3.html",
                        last_id_jpg = last_id_jpg
                       )
```

with :

```
<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename=last_id_jpg) }}" alt="no picture">
```

or :

```
<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='last_id_jpg') }}" alt="no picture">
```

But can't find the path to the designed image (the webpage displays "no picture"). I made some researches and [everything seems OK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47871185/python-flask-url-for-static-with-variable)

What is wrong in my code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo on your `last_id_jpg`. It should be

```py
last_id_jpg = r"img/articles/43.jpg" # article with s
```

not

```py
last_id_jpg = r"img/article/43.jpg"
```